# Can php5 coexist with php4?

Tags: php, apache

I use apache. 
I want to let php4 coexist with php5 in one server, 
but what kind of method will there be?

Answer (score 9):

There are a *lot* of guides on how to do this:

- [Running Apache2 With PHP5 And PHP4 At The Same Time](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_with_php5_and_php4)
- [Running both PHP4 and PHP5](http://my.opera.com/zomg/blog/2007/08/12/running-both-php4-and-php5)

... [and more](http://www.google.com/search?q=run+both+php4+and+php5)

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen hosts do is to keep interpreting .php files as PHP4, but use .php5 for PHP5.

Comment: Does that still work if you use Option Multiviews to hide the file extensions?  I tend to use /path/to/script with multiviews to refer to /path/to/script.php

Answer (score 1):

My host lets me put a .htaccess with a special directive to say 'process php pages in this folder and subfolders as PHP5'

Ask your host, they may have something similiar.